# Application file with Python and FFMPEG

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Not sure if this is the right place for this question - but I have a `python` script which uses `ffmpeg`. I want to create an application/executable file which includes the dependencies of `Python` and `ffmpeg` which I can distribute so that others don't have to install `Python` or `ffmpeg` on their machine to run the script.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether my answer will be sufficient, but I hope it may lead to the answer.

First, FFMPEG is not a problem, it's very independent, needs no installation. However, I know nothing of Python nor do I know your target machines, the target operating systems.

There's a very popular online video downloader developed under Python (which can also use FFMPEG) called: youtube-dl. This runs independently under Windows without any additional installations. Maybe worth checking out?

youtube-dl link here: [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/)